# Applying a differential operator to the multivariable fundamental theorem of calculus equation

Tags: calculus

I'm referring to this result:

> If $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$, then for each $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there exist $C^{\infty}$ functions $H_i$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
> $$F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i-a^i)H_i(x)$$

But I'm not sure what happens if I apply a differential operator to both sides (like a derivation $D$) - more specifically I'm not sure at what point should each term be evaluated. Acting $D$ on both sides I'll get
$$DF=\sum_{i=1}^n\big[(x^i-a^i).DH_i+H_i.Dx^i\big]$$

If I try evaluating the non-differentiated RHS terms at $a$, like this
$$DF=\sum_{i=1}^n\big[(x^i-a^i)|_{x=a}.DH_i+H_i(a).Dx^i\big]$$

I can't just bring the $x=a$ thing out of thin air, can I? Should the LHS also be evaluated at $x=a$? i.e.
$$DF|_{x=a}=\sum_{i=1}^nH_i(a).Dx^i|_{x=a}$$

And then finally, if $H_i=X_i(F)$ for some operator $X_i$, can we say that $H_i(x)=X_i(F)(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus conclude from the above equation that
$$DF|_{x=a}=\sum_{i=1}^nDx^i|_{x=a}.X_i(F)(a)=\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^nDx^i.X_i(F)\bigg]_{x=a}$$
Now since both sides are equal for arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $D=\sum_{i=1}^nDx^i.X_i$

Is this fine? I'm not sure at all since there are so many steps and I don't know where I might have made a wrong assumption or step.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x^{(j)}= (x_1,\ldots,x_j,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n),$$ We have $$F(x)-F(a)=\sum_{j=1}^n[F(x^{(j)})-F(x^{(j-1)})]=\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-a_j){F(x^{(j)})-F(x^{(j-1)})\over x_j-a_j}$$